# How do I install correct version of NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm very new to coding, and am using Linux Pop! OS. I'm working on a project with React and NodeJS and npm, but it says I have to have at least the 14th version of Node to create a React App, and mine is v12.22.9

I've tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, but the node version doesnt change. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I see on the [NodeJS download website](https://nodejs.org/en/) that the most current version is 19 and have downloaded that to my downloads folder, but I don't know how to tell vscode to use that version.

Comment: is installing via snapcraft an acceptable option for you? As for the one you downloaded, what (kind of file) exactly did you download? (what's the file extension?)

Comment: I don't really know tbh, but the filetype I downloaded was FreeFileSync_12.0_Linux.tar.gz

Comment: well, [unzipping it](https://askubuntu.com/q/25347/1624654) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Install from source:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

or use [fnm (fast and simple Node.js version manager)](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#fnm) to have best solution - [GH repo](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm#using-a-script-macoslinux) - which allows you to install, uninstall, switch Node versions as you like.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and it gave me this: "Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_19.7.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: Try making cleanup like this: 
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157#issuecomment-849595760

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below commands the upgrade your nodeJS version. I am using that command multiple times and it's always working for me. this command is to change your nodeJS current version to version 14.

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash

> source ~/.profile

> nvm install 14.15.5